# Creating a new column and rows in dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
id_1    id_desc    cat_1    cat_2
111      ask        ele     phone
222      ask hr     ele     phone
333      ask hr dk  ele     phone
444      askh       ele     phone
```

If `cat_1`, `cat_2` are same for multiple `id_1`, that association need to be captured as a new column.

Need an output like this,

```
id_1    id_desc        cat_1    cat_2   id_2
111      ask             ele    phone   222
111      ask             ele    phone   333
111      ask             ele    phone   444
222      ask hr          ele    phone   111
222      ask hr          ele    phone   333
222      ask hr          ele    phone   444
333      ask hr dk       ele    phone   111
333      ask hr dk       ele    phone   222
333      ask hr dk       ele    phone   444
```

how to get this done in python?

Comment: sorry about the formatting.

Comment: Thanks @Wondercricket for fixing the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to come up with anything particularly elegant, but this should get the job done:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[111, 'ask', 'ele', 'phone'], 
                   [222, 'ask_hr', 'ele', 'phone'], 
                   [333, 'ask_hr_dk', 'ele', 'phone'], 
                   [444, 'askh', 'ele', 'phone']], 
                   columns=['id_1', 'id_desc', 'cat_1', 'cat_2'])

grouped = df.groupby(by=['cat_1', 'cat_2'])  # group by the columns you want to be identical

data = []  # a list to store all unique groups

# In your example, this loop is not needed, but this generalizes to more than 1 pair
# of cat_1 and cat_2 values
for group in grouped.groups:  
    n_rows = grouped.get_group(group).shape[0]  # how many unique id's in a group
    all_data = np.tile(grouped.get_group(group).values, (n_rows, 1))  # tile the data n_row times
    ids = np.repeat(grouped.get_group(group)['id_1'].values, n_rows)  # repeat the ids n_row times
    data += [np.c_[all_data, ids]]  # concat the two sets of data and add to list

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(data), columns=['id_1', 'id_desc', 'cat_1', 'cat_2', 'id_2'])
```

The basic idea is to group your data by the `cat_1` and `cat_2` columns (using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)), use [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to create copies of each group as many times as there are unique values of `id_1` in the group, and concatenate the result with the unique `id_1` values (one value per group of data).

If you don't want `id_1` to ever be the same as `id_2`, just select the rows where they don't match:

```
df_2 = df_2[df_2['id_1'] != df_2['id_2']]
```

And if you want them sorted on `id_1`:

```
df_2.sort_values('id_1', inplace=True)
```

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" at grouped.get_group(group).shape[0]

Comment: I am able to run the above code without any errors. I would need more details about your code to be able to help you further. One thing you should verify is that you have `for group in grouped.groups:` as the beginning of your `for` loop. If you just have `for group in groups:`, you would get this error because `group` would be a DataFrame, not a tuple.

Comment: oh, sorry my bad. Also I got it working this way as well, for name, group in grouped:
    n_rows = grouped.get_group(name).shape[0]
    all_data = np.tile(grouped.get_group(name).values, (n_rows, 1))
    ids = np.repeat(grouped.get_group(name)['id_1'].values, n_rows)
    data += [np.c_[all_data, ids]]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to do this using spark api's in a parallelized way?